# What is the addition in the re-released version of Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, alternate-version

I heard about the *Avengers: Endgame* re-release version with additional footage in the US, but I can't see any news about its Indian release. So I was doubtful if it ever gets released here and quite curious to know what are the differences in the new version. So what are that additional scene(s) and changes?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For the sake of completeness...

Per [**Polygon.com**](https://www.polygon.com/2019/6/29/19926714/avengers-endgame-rerelease-new-footage-changes)

> Don’t go into this re-release hoping for some deleted scenes. The changes are minor, and the new footage is simply presented at the very end of the film.
>
> If you’ve seen Avengers: Endgame several times already, you may realize that some scenes in the re-release are slightly extended, like Peter Parker and Ned Leeds’ reunion. During the end credits showcasing the original Avengers and their actors’ autographs, the silhouettes are lighter, making it easier to see their faces. It’s only after the credits have rolled completely and a brief intro from director Anthony Russo that you’ll get to see the new content Marvel promised.
>
> The first thing that plays is an earnest tribute to Stan Lee following his passing late last year. Similar to a special feature short on a DVD release, the tribute features footage of Lee on the set of various MCU movies, interacting with the cast and directors. After all that Lee went through during the final years of his life, seeing him smiling and cracking jokes feels sorely missed. It’s a sweet look at his life and the impact he’s had on others. And of course, it closes out with the now classic line: “Stan, we love you 3000.”
>
> Lee’s tribute is followed by a look at what would’ve been the return of Mark Ruffalo’s original Hulk. In the five years after Thanos has wiped half the universe’s population, you’ll recall Bruce Banner’s and the Hulk’s personas merged, allowing him to have Hulk’s size and strength and Banner’s smarts at the same time. In the deleted scene, we see the Hulk, in the purple and black bodysuit he wears in the later scenes of the movie, save civilians from a burning building before reuniting with Steve, Natasha, and Scott.
>
> The scene is unfinished, and uses a CG placeholder model for the Hulk instead of the fully animated, mocap Hulk we’ve come to know and love. It also notably features a cameo from Reginald VelJohnson as one of the officers on the scene. VelJohnson, of course, played Sgt. Al Powell in Die Hard (and was also Carl Winslow, the cop/dad hassled by Urkel on Family Matters). Interestingly, this makes VelJohnson the second actor in Avengers: Endgame to have been in a movie mentioned by Scott Lang during the film, after Sebastian Stan, who was in Hot Tub Time Machine.
>
> Closing out the extra content is, of course, a sneak peek of Spider-Man: Far From Home. The scene is set early in the film, and features Nick Fury and Maria Hill making their way to Mexico to investigate a chaotic scene. The former SHIELD agents meet Jake Gyllenhaal’s Mysterio, in the midst of battling a creature made of swirling sand. “You don’t want any part of this,” Mysterio says before firing green energy bolts at it — and closing out the scene.

Comment: TL;DR version->  *nothing interesting then*..... isn't it?

Comment: @Vishwa Basically...nope. They just want the record. I'll wait for the DVD.

Comment: @Vishwa Pretty much. The cynic in me says that this is an attempt to push Endgame into the top of the Highest Grossing of All Time (currently occupied by Avatar). Given that, I kind of find the description of the Stan Lee tribute as "earnest" a little bit gross, but YMMV.

Comment: @DoctorPenguin earnest, resulting from or showing sincere and intense conviction. What's gross about that?

Comment: Because the way his death is being exploited to sell a few more tickets to get a big studio a world record, and framing it it as a respectful tribute is blatantly insincere and IMO distasteful. Hence why "earnest" was put in quotes, because I think the use of that word is simply dishonest.

Comment: @Paulie_D That'll be the possible best idea, may be they'll do some special editions, box sets etc. and I think you meant Blu Ray, not the DVD. it'll be few months I think.waiting would be the worst

Comment: @DoctorPenguin every cameo Stan did, was very similar to what they trying to do now mate, Although we see Stan as a symbol, studio just saw him as a more sales pitch, thats all. I think we had some interesting questions about that in here... and yeah, agree with that **earnest** bit. that's low